# Does a separate agent need to be installed for environments in Azure Devops? (when deployment agents already installed)

Tags: linux, azure, azure-devops

I've been looking at trying the new Environments feature in Azure Devops [documented here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments?view=azure-devops)

I looked at setting one up through the UI and it gives a bash script to install the agent like what I've put below:

```
mkdir azagent;cd azagent;curl -fkSL -o vstsagent.tar.gz https://vstsagentpackage.azureedge.net/agent/2.169.1/vsts-agent-linux-x64-2.169.1.tar.gz;tar -zxvf vstsagent.tar.gz; if [ -x "$(command -v systemctl)" ]; then ./config.sh --environment --environmentname "SIT" --acceptteeeula --agent $HOSTNAME --url <Our URL> --work _work --projectname <project name> --auth PAT --token <PAT Token> --runasservice; sudo ./svc.sh install; sudo ./svc.sh start; else ./config.sh --environment --environmentname "Dev" --acceptteeeula --agent $HOSTNAME --url <Our URL> --work _work --projectname 'Beehive' --auth PAT --token <PAT Token>; ./run.sh; fi
```

This looks like it will install the agent for you. However I already have deployment agents installed on this machine and don't want to replace it for now. Do I have to install a separate agent for these environments or can I configure the current deployment agents to use environments as well?

Hope this is clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I have to install a separate agent for these environments or can I configure the current deployment agents to use environments as well?

The answer is yes. We have to install a separate agent for these environments, could not configure the current deployment agents to use environments.

That because the Environments and Deployment agents are different.

[Deployment groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/deployment-groups/?view=azure-devops):

> > A deployment group is **a logical set of deployment target machines that have agents installed on each one. Deployment groups represent the physical environments**; for example, “Dev”, “Test”, “UAT”, and “Production”. In effect, a deployment group is just another grouping of agents, much like an agent pool.

[Environments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/environments?view=azure-devops):

> > Environment represents **a collection of resources** such as namespaces within Kubernetes clusters, Azure Web Apps, virtual machines, databases, which can be targeted by deployments from a pipeline.

They both have the same theory in actual deployment. But, **since Deployment group jobs are not yet supported in YAML**. In this case, the Environments comes up.

**While environment at its core is a grouping of resources, the resources themselves represent actual deployment targets.**

There are some other differences, for example, we cannot create the deployment group directly in the pipeline, but we can create environments directly in pipeline. And environment can record the commit / work item during deployment. It is more convenient to track code changes, bug fixes, etc.

So, we could not configure the current deployment agents to use environments.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks this answers my question! Appreciated